# Can metaphors in popular culture help with explaining agile or waterfall to clients?

Tags: agile, waterfall, clients

After reading [this blog post that suggests that the Death Star was an agile project](http://greatandsmallblog.com/2011/03/07/the-death-star-was-an-agile-project/) I was wondering if using metaphors is a good way of describing methodologies in a slightly fun way.

'Movie x demonstrated agile because of a, b, c' - 'Movie y demonstrated waterfall because of f, g, h' - would this help clients understand what the concepts actually mean?

Comment: The best metaphor for Agile is a waterfall.  The best metaphor for Waterfall is a metal frame into which concrete will be poured.  Popular culture ... I don't know about that.

Comment: All abstractions (metaphors, in this case) are leaky. The trick would be to close the leak to a trickle as best as possible. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, use whatever metaphor or tool you can to explain the difference.

You might find the following articles helpful:

[Agile Mindset, Waterfall Mindset](http://www.vertabase.com/blog/managing-expectations-on-projects-agile-mindset-waterfall-mindset/#more-73) uses agile and waterfall as metaphors themselves.

[What We Talk About When We Talk About Projects](http://www.fusionauthority.com/techniques/4798-what-we-talk-about-when-we-talk-about-projects.htm) discusses the importance of creating "boundary objects" -linguistic tools or project artifacts to improve communication on projects.

Comment: Nice work on the blog articles.

Answer (score 3):

waterfall is like artillery: a lot of setup, tons of prep work, massive amounts of ordinance, extremely precise aiming, difficulty hitting a moving target, and takes out a city block wherever it lands

agile is like a missile: arm, fire, aim...aim...aim...aim...aim...

Answer (score 2):

Technical matter and business can easily be some kind of arid. And everything which can be useful to make things more understandable is good. Just be careful with metaphors: they can easily bring with them some false ideas.

Of course, the metaphor needs to be well fitted for the people you're aiming. For example, Star Wars is maybe not a good metaphor if you want to explain agile methods to the C level of your company...

Answer (score 2):

Funny question.

I think of Matrix as Iterative, as The Architect mention that is the sixth version of the Matrix, so machines build in a iterative way.

Evan Almighty construction of the Noa´s Arc, is a good example of waterfall.

Answer (score 2):

Of course.  What area of thought or practice is not helped by metaphor?  What after all is thought?

I suggest the movie "Rain Man".  Tom Cruise for Agile, Dustin Hoffman for Waterfall.